# File as resident or non resident for Massachusetts when one spouse is resident and other is non resident

Tags: united-states, taxes, massachusetts

I have been a non-resident of Massachusetts for the entire of 2013 while my spouse has been a resident. Also we jointly own a real estate property in the state.

In that case, while filing taxes through turbo tax, it only allows us to select one option for both of us since we use "Married Filing Jointly" option for our federal taxes. Turbo tax selects the Non-Resident option based on my name being the first one on the form.

The questions that I have are as below:

- Is this correct?
- Is there a way for both of us to file different Mass state taxes based on our individual residency or do we just have to either pick one?
- Which one is more suitable to use in this case?

Comment: In Illinois and Indiana, you must file as a resident if either spouse is a resident if filing jointly, the only way to do different state taxes here is to file married filing separately, which may and may not be beneficial depending on your situation. I'd imagine MA would be similar, but I can't say for certain.

Comment: One thing from MA website:
http://www.mass.gov/dor/individuals/filing-and-payment-information/guide-to-personal-income-tax/filing-status.html#MarriedJoint
If taxpayers are married as of the last day of the year but have a Massachusetts residency tax year that begins and ends on different days, they must file married filing separately assuming each spouse has a requirement to file.

Not sure how or if TurboTax can handle this.